# Eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ where $a_{ij} = 1/a_{ji}$ and $a_{ii}=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix whose diagonal entries are $a_{ii} = 1$ and whose off-diagonal entries are $$a_{ij} = \frac{1}{a_{ji}}$$ where $a_{ij} > 0$. Are the eigenvalues of $A$ always real? What more can we say about them?

I was thinking about it but I can't figure out anything. Can you help me?

EDIT: and what if in the upper triangle we have only values greather than 1?

Comment: They need not always be real. Consider the $3 \times 3$ matrix according to your specifications with first row $(1, 2, 3)$ and a $2$ in the row 2, column 3 position.

Comment: Some people call them "currency exchange matrices" (or something like that).

Comment: thank you for the answers. What if in the upper triangle we have only values greather than 1? (That was the original question, i miss wrote it ahahha)

Comment: Note that if you take the logarithm of the matrix entry-wise, you obtain a skew-symmetric matrix. Unfortunately, I don't see how this is useful.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+of+%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B1%2F2%2C1%2C2%5D%2C%5B1%2F3%2C1%2F2%2C1%5D%5D note the complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @Ulivai When you say that was the original question, does that mean there is an original source?  Please reference it if possible :).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052280/339790

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
0 =  \begin{vmatrix}
1 - \lambda & a & b\\ 
\frac{1}{a} & 1 - \lambda & c \\
\frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{c} & 1 - \lambda
\end{vmatrix} &= (1 - \lambda)((1 - \lambda)^2 - 1) + a \left ( \frac{c}{b} - \frac{1-\lambda}{a} \right) + b \left(\frac{1}{ac} - \frac{1-\lambda}{b} \right )\\
&= (1 - \lambda)^3 - (1 - \lambda) +  \frac{ac}{b} - (1-\lambda) + \frac{b}{ac} - (1-\lambda )\\
 &= (1 - \lambda)^3 - 3(1-\lambda ) + \frac{ac}{b} + \frac{b}{ac} \\
 &= -\lambda^3 + 3 \lambda^2 + \frac{a^2c^2 + b^2}{abc} - 2 \\
\end{align*}

No reason for [that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20-x%5E3%20%2B%203%20x%5E2%20%2B%20k-2) to have real roots.